# How can I allow download in sandboxed iframe using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="HTML_HERE" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

This is the sandboxed iframe, you are not allowed to modify this and add 'allow-downloads' or any sandbox properties. You need Javascript to sove this.

Comment: you just wanted this iframe to be viewable, and not allow users to make any changes to it?

Comment: ..............yup .............

Answer (score 3):

When I make an iframe with those attributes, I am absolutely able to download a file (may not work on SO, but if you copy the code to a local file and try it, see what happens):

```html
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin" id=f ></iframe>



<textarea id=t>
<a id=u></a>
<button id="dao">Do it!?</button>
<script>
dao.onclick = () => {
    console.log("hi")
    u.href = URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([
            "hello there, just testing!?"
        ])
    )
    u.download = "hi.txt"
    u.click()
}
</script>
</textarea>
<script>
f.src = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([
        t.value
    ], {
        type: "text/html"
    })
)
</script>
```

Comment: This does not work in some versions of Firefox but I verified in Chrome and some others it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

'allow-downloads' is newly introduced value for the sandbox attribute in the iframe.

```
sandbox="allow-downloads"
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#browser_compatibility

Comment: How do I set this on my browser? I have no control over the page source, but Firefox is blocking my download due to this. How do I disable this?